# C# User Input Loop Skipping Code

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

very new to coding. I posted a question about how to check for invalid user inputs without crashing the program which was very quickly answered so thank you! I've now got the loop set up to reject anything but a value between 1-10 and am trying to have it go to the next attribute to enter but can't figure out how to stop it from skipping to the end of the code. Here's my code:

```
        UInt32 attributePoints = 25;
        bool validInput = false;
        string inputStrength;
        string inputSpeed;
        UInt32 validStrength = 0;
        UInt32 validSpeed = 0;
        while (!validInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have: " + attributePoints + " attribute points remaining to choose from");
            Console.Write("Please enter a value between 1-10 for strength: ");
            inputStrength = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!UInt32.TryParse(inputStrength, out validStrength))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for strength.");
            }
            else if (validStrength < 0 || validStrength > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for strength.");
            }
            else
            {
                validInput = true;
            }

            while (!validInput)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a value between 1-10 for speed: ");
                inputSpeed = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!UInt32.TryParse(inputSpeed, out validSpeed))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for speed.");
                }
                else if (validSpeed < 0 || validSpeed > 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for speed.");
                }
                else
                {
                    validInput = true;
                }

            }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Strength Value = {0}", validStrength));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Speed Value = {0}", validSpeed));
    }
```

If I run the program intentionally putting in an invalid input for speed, the end result is this:

Please enter a value between 1-10 for strength: a

Input was not a valid value for strength.

Please enter a value between 1-10 for speed: 5

Strenght value = 0

Speed Value = 5

How can I get this code to keep asking for a value for strength until a valid number is given and then move on to speed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
    UInt32 attributePoints = 25;
    string inputStrength;
    string inputSpeed;
    UInt32 validStrength = 0;
    UInt32 validSpeed = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have: " + attributePoints + " attribute points remaining to choose from");
        Console.Write("Please enter a value between 1-10 for strength: ");
        inputStrength = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!UInt32.TryParse(inputStrength, out validStrength))
            Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for strength.");
        else if (validStrength < 0 || validStrength > 10)
            Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for strength.");
        else
            break;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a value between 1-10 for speed: ");
        inputSpeed = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!UInt32.TryParse(inputSpeed, out validSpeed))
            Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for speed.");
        else if (validSpeed < 0 || validSpeed > 10)
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid value for speed.");
        else
             break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Strength Value = {0}", validStrength));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Speed Value = {0}", validSpeed));
```